# Stream webcam to Android

Tags: webcam, android

I want to monitor web camera on Ubuntu to my android. What application can I use? I like [iCam](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.skjm.icam&feature=search_result) but it works ony on windows. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can install [Zoneminder](http://www.zoneminder.com/) on your Ubuntu desktop from the Ubuntu repository.  Follow the Zoneminder instructions to connect any type of camera (USB, IP, CCTV).

On your Android mobile, download camera monitoring software such as "tinyCam Monitor FREE" or "IP Cam Viewer".  Both work well with Zoneminder.

You will likely need to open a port on your router to allow a connection to your desktop from outside.  Additionally, you may prefer to use a Dynamic DNS provider such as [DynDNS](http://dyn.com/dns/dyndns-free/) so that you don't need to keep changing your IP address configuration.

All of the above can be done using free software and services.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a little bit difficult to set up but it's the only one I know :P

http://code.google.com/p/cwatchthehamster/

Answer (score 0):

[IpWebcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam) is an application for Android that lets you access the device camera on your desktop. You can view it on your browser. I don't know if is this that you are looking for, but I hope it helps.

Comment: he wants to watch the laptop cam on his android, not the other way

Answer (score 0):

Why not try VLC, then access the cam from your phone's browser.
Here's how they did it.
http://xmodulo.com/live-stream-video-webcam-linux.html

Comment: VLC on Android? VLC has to do with webcams? I don't think so.

Comment: VLC has to do with webcams? Yes. It can view, stream, save or whatever a `local/usb/ip/whatever` webcam. VLC is the Swiss Army knife of audio/video tools.